# AJAX success scope clarification

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scope

I have a function that executes an AJAX call like the following:

```
function myFunc(variable) {
    $.ajax({
        [...]
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(variable)
        },
        [...]
    });
}
```

Now, can someone please explain why the `variable` is undefined in success while if I reassign it like in the following example, it has the value?

```
function myFunc(variable) {
    var variable2 = variable;
    $.ajax({
        [...]
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(variable2)
        },
        [...]
    });
}
```

Comment: Unable to replicate given the code you've shown: https://jsfiddle.net/8gw1ooqL/. A more complete code example would help here, showing the context you're calling `myFunc()` in, as well as where `variable` is set and what it contains

Comment: From the code you show, it is all dependent on how you call `myFunc`. ie `myFunc('something')` vs `myFunc()`. So if you are calling myFunc with an argument, then you will need to show more code as nothing currently shown would cause what you are saying

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the function is being called from the `initComplete` of a [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) instance. Variable is a `tfoot` object from an HTML table

Comment: @PatrickEvans maybe I wasn't clear in the explaination but calling the function exactly the same way, the variable is beaing displayed in the second case and not in the first. So the variable is of course populated (otherwise even the second case won't have worked.